# Differentiation and continous functions

Tags: functions, derivatives, continuity

Is it true that every Lipschitz continuous function has a continuous derivative ?

I am asking out of curiosity because I can't find a counter example. 
Thanks!!

EDIT : The function is differentiable

Comment: what is the domain and co-domain of the function?

Answer (score 6):

No. Lipschitz functions need not be differentiable at all. Try 
$$
f(x)=|x|
$$
with Lipschitz constant 1.

It is true that Lipschitz functions are differentiable everywhere but a set of measure zero, thanks to Rademacher's Theorem.

Comment: what about lipschitz functions that are differentiable?

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo that's a good question, I am not sure of the answer. The derivative is bounded obviously, but I don't see an easy way to bound differences in the derivative range in terms of distances in the domain. Is it false? If not, any hints?

Comment: Thanks for the answer  but this counter example is somehow artificial. I meant a function which is uniquely defined everywhere in R .

Comment: I don't know what you mean. This function is defined on all of R

Comment: sorry  I meant  the function is differentiable.